# How I could add a preloader to load content div jquery?

Tags: jquery, onclick, preloader

Hi I have this jQuery to load content into a div with a button code, but the content you are loading includes images of much size and would like to appear as it is loaded in the div preload an animated gif, how could lead to out?

Code jquery:

```
function chargue(div, of)
{
$(div).load(of, function() {
});
}
```

The button:

```
<a href="#next" onClick="chargue('#left','change.php')">CHANGE</a>
```

CSS div #left:

```
#left {
    width: 744px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, can you show me an example of how you could implement it?

Comment: Please refer below answer I have post it just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change to content of your `div` to an animated loading gif, then when your ajax `get()` is finished, replace your `div` content with the results.

```
function chargue(div, of)
{
  //insert loading gif
  $(div).html('<img src="image/loading.gif">');

  //fetch larger images
  $.get(of, function(results) {
    $(div).html(results);
  });
}
```

Comment: It seems to work well but can not see it because localhost load very quickly, could give time to display even a second?

Comment: If you want to wait to show results, use `setTimeout(function(){  $(div).html(results); }, 1000);` instead of `$(div).html(results);`. Then adjust your time accordingly.

Comment: One last thing that has happened to me, what to display with a fade in? And to parse the FB.XFBML.parse (document.getElementById ('comments-disk'));
and twttr.widgets.load ();

Comment: I managed to fix the rest, but do not load the twttr.widgets.load (); It's very weird

Comment: Where is this `twttr.widgets.load ();` taking place? On the page you are loading in? Are any errors showing up in the console log?

Comment: Dustin thanks for answering, look I opened a new question because in the end I could not integrate the three things with your code preload gif, stop by and take a look to see what can be failing.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836578/it-does-not-work-or-the-fade-in-and-load-the-twitter-widget-where-could-he-be-w

Answer (score 1):

```
function chargue(div, of)
{ 
    $('#loader').show();
    $(div).load(of, function(response, status, xhr) { 
      if(status == 'success'){ 
        $('#loader').hide();
      }
   });
}
```

Please create one child div under **#left** div. And put your loader *gif*  into that. Note: **#loder** div should be hide by default.